# How can I run a jQuery animation only once on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use Javascript to detect when a user scrolls down past a certain height on my site, and that then my "social" icons fade in once they reach that scroll breakpoint.

The thing I'm trying to figure out is how can I only run the fadeTo once the alpha hits 1 and lock it in? So that when the user scrolls up and down again the fadeIn doesn't happen again over and over unless they initiate a page reload which would reset everything.

```
//SCROLL
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
//SOCIAL ICONS
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1750) {
    $(".img-social .gith").stop(true).fadeTo(250, 1);
    $(".img-social .inst").stop(true).fadeTo(450, 1);
    $(".img-social .twit").stop(true).fadeTo(650, 1);
    $(".img-social .drib").stop(true).fadeTo(850, 1);
    $(".img-social .link").stop(true).fadeTo(1050, 1);
} else {
    $(".img-social .gith").stop(true).fadeTo(10, 0);
    $(".img-social .inst").stop(true).fadeTo(10, 0);
    $(".img-social .twit").stop(true).fadeTo(10, 0);
    $(".img-social .drib").stop(true).fadeTo(10, 0);
    $(".img-social .link").stop(true).fadeTo(10, 0);
}
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put following code within your first `if` condition to `off` the `scroll` event once you run the code:

```
$(window).on("scroll.socialIcon", function () {
    if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 1750 ) {
        // ...
        $(window).off("scroll.socialIcon"); // last line
    } else {
        //...
    }
});
```

So the `scroll.socialIcon` (namespaced) event won't response anymore.

Comment: Awesome, this worked out really well and thanks for the edit! I have a bunch of other things I fade in on scroll and so the scroll.mySection works out perfectly!

Comment: Curious because I haven't tried it: won't this prevent the fadeout because it's no longer listening for scrolling? Can you explain more about namespacing listeners?

Comment: It should not listen once it does the `fade` as `OP` asked it for.

Answer (score 3):

use a boolean to record whether it's happened or not:

```
// SET BOOLEAN
var scrolled = false;

//SCROLL
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
//SOCIAL ICONS
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1750 && !scrolled) {
        $(".img-social .gith").stop(true).fadeTo(250, 1);
        $(".img-social .inst").stop(true).fadeTo(450, 1);
        $(".img-social .twit").stop(true).fadeTo(650, 1);
        $(".img-social .drib").stop(true).fadeTo(850, 1);
        $(".img-social .link").stop(true).fadeTo(1050, 1);
        scrolled = true;
    } else {
        $(".img-social .gith").stop(true).fadeTo(10, 0);
        $(".img-social .inst").stop(true).fadeTo(10, 0);
        $(".img-social .twit").stop(true).fadeTo(10, 0);
        $(".img-social .drib").stop(true).fadeTo(10, 0);
        $(".img-social .link").stop(true).fadeTo(10, 0);
        scrolled = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about using boolean in jS. I'll give this a try.

Comment: I think the !scrolled needs to be a seperate if statement inside the scrollTop > 1750 statement. Otherwise it will immediately be set to false again when it can't enter the first if.